# Auto fill the URL field from the DOI field in JabRef

Tags: latex, bibtex, biblatex, doi

In JabRef (v5.1) if I use the "new entry" tab to build a reference using the DOI I would like it to populate the URL field with the DOI append behind https://doi.org/, for example for if I use the doi "10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551" I would like it to fill in the URL filed with https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551.

Is there any way to do this, either during the reference creation stage or after?

Note that doi2bib.org does this, for 10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551 it returns url = https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551

Here is the full bibtex entry from doi2bib.org that does this as desired.

```
@article{Downey2020,
  doi = {10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551},
  year = {2020},
  month = apr,
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {138},
  pages = {106551},
  author = {Austin Downey and Jonathan Hong and Jacob Dodson and Michael Carroll and James Scheppegrell},
  title = {Millisecond model updating for structures experiencing unmodeled high-rate dynamic events},
  journal = {Mechanical Systems and Signal Processing}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the URL field at all, that's only unnecessary and redundant information. If you use a suitable bibliography style, e.g. the default style of `biblatex`, the doi field will automatically print as clickable link to the correct website:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{Downey2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I use a .bst file that I have modified from the IEEE trans .bst because I want a link to everything, even if I don't have a DOI but have a URL. For example, I don't want my references to have both a URL link defined by a doi and just the DOI if they are both there. I can post a picture of my reference if that helps.

Comment: @AustinDowney With biblatex, such conditionals are really easy

Comment: What is the name of the .bst file for the "default style of biblatex". Maybe I can pull some code out of this. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @AustinDowney biblatex does not use bst files

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I got something kinda working, but a follow-up question is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307157/adding-url-link-to-function-in-bst-file

Comment: There is no real answer to this question, but the answer to the follow-up question is the closest I have come. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307157/adding-url-link-to-function-in-bst-file